# How do I get my react js app to start watching my sass files?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, sass

How do I get my react js app to start watching my sass files?
I did `npm i sass` vs `npm i node-sass` because I learned that `node-sass` is depreciated, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with automatic sass watching? (also, I have the latest version of node installed)

I know when you're not using a framework you have to type into the terminal " sass --watch input.scss output.css.", do I have to do the same in react js?
Also in my components I have imported the main.scss sheet!

this is the error I get when I try to run my react js app:

Failed to compile
./src/components/Login.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './scss/main.scss' in '/Users/karinapichardo/Desktop/login-project/src/components'

what am I missing to do? any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is your `scss` folder inside `src/components`? Maybe you just need to fix the relative path.

Comment: I have my scss folder inside my src folder, not my src/components folder, is that a problem? @JonUleis

Comment: thanks for answering

Comment: Are you using custom `webpack` configuration or maybe generated the app with `create-react-app`?

Comment: I generated the app with create-react-app @GiannosCharalambous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to import the SCSS file from the directory where `Login.js` is.

You should modify your import path to be like this:

```js
import "../scss/main.scss"; // 2 dots at start of path
```

instead of like this:

```js
import "./scss/main.scss";
```

Which will essentially navigate to the `src` directory before accessing the rest of the path

Comment: I will take a guess and say that you are already familiar with path navigation and just missed it that you don't have `..` ;) ( Happens to the best of us )

Comment: hahaha yeah, just got it to work! before seeing your answer, im going to mark it as answered, and leave it incase someone runs into the same problem

Comment: thank you giannos

Comment: Could be, hope you have a code-fruitful day